# Present 2-column group/subitem data in a different format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem that I hope you can help me with.

I have 2 lists with categories that I wish to present in a different way (see image). Columns B+C are my input and columns E+F are my desired output. the content of B+C will be dynamic and so I hope to find formulas that can help me keep the E+F columns updated.

column B includes groups and column C includes subitems
every list of subitems in column F should start with a subitem that is equal to the group name
If there is a group in column B with no subitem in column C, the subitems will just present the group name and then move on (like the "travel" example).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv3rs.png)

Thank you very much!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: It makes it tricky that you have the name of the primary group as a member of the child group as well.  From the image, it looks like a pivot table would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (in `E2`):

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    {
      IFNA(VLOOKUP(
        SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B:B) * 2 + COUNTA(B:B), 1, ROW(B2)),
        {
            MATCH(
              UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, B:B <> "")),
              B:B,
            )
          + SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B:B), 1,, 2),
          UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, B:B <> ""))
        },
        2,
      )),
      IFNA(VLOOKUP(
        SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B:B) * 2 + COUNTA(B:B), 1, ROW(B2)),
        {
          {
              MATCH(
                UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, B:B <> "")),
                B:B,
              )
            + SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B:B), 1, 1, 2),
            UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, B:B <> ""))
          };
          FILTER(
            {
                ROW(C:C)
              + VLOOKUP(
                  ROW(C:C),
                  {
                    MATCH(
                      UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B, B:B <> "")),
                      B:B,
                    ),
                    SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(B:B), 1,, 2)
                  },
                  2
                )
              + 2,
              C:C
            },
            B:B <> ""
          )
        },
        2,
      ))
    }
  ),
  "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL OR Col2 IS NOT NULL",
)
```

[image]

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much

Comment: May I ask - how would you simplify this query if it was not needed to have the name of the primary group as member of the child group? (e.g. F3 value "AA" not included, F9 "BB" value not included).

Comment: @WilliamPontoppidan what about CC? Should it present because of an empty cell (`C8`)?

Comment: @WilliamPontoppidan if so, then it will be a bit simpler and a bit modified: [see here](https://pastebin.com/raw/idJduurC).

Comment: Thank you Kishkin, this has really enabled me to be more productive.